# Changing zIndex with a Function does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to change the zIndex of the Div Boxes so that the Div Box which is targeted by the mouse will be focused and every other Div Box around it will go behind it. But the zIndex does not change and the next Div Box is always overlapping the previous one.

The zIndex will change to 1 on a mouseover and will be changed to -1 on a mouseout.

I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

```js
function chartOuterDivScaleMax(i) {
    
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('chartouterdiv');
    var b = document.getElementsByClassName('logocontainer');
    var c = document.getElementsByClassName('highdiv');
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName('lowdiv');
    
    a[i].style.transform = "scale(1.25)";
    a[i].style.zIndex = 1;
    
    b[i].style.transform = "scale(1.25)";
    b[i].style.transform = "translate(0px, 10px)";
    b[i].style.zIndex = 1;
    
    c[i].style.height = "70px";
    c[i].style.zIndex = 1;
   
    d[i].style.height = "35px";
    d[i].style.zIndex = 1;
    

    
}

function chartOuterDivScaleMin(i) {
    
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('chartouterdiv');
    var b = document.getElementsByClassName('logocontainer');
    var c = document.getElementsByClassName('highdiv');
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName('lowdiv');
    
    a[i].style.transform = "scale(1)";
    a[i].style.zIndex = -1;
    
    b[i].style.transform = "scale(1)";
    b[i].style.zIndex = -1;
   
    c[i].style.height = "55px";
    c[i].style.zIndex = -1;
      
    d[i].style.height = "50px";
    d[i].style.zIndex = -1;
    
       
}

function iterateScaleFunction() {
    
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("chartouterdiv");
    
    for (let i = 0; i <= elements.length; i++ ){
        
        elements[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {chartOuterDivScaleMax(i)}, false);
        elements[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {chartOuterDivScaleMin(i)}, false);
    }
}
```

```css
.chartouterdiv{
    height:115px;
    width:215px;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: scale(1);
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 0;
}

.chartinnerdiv{
    height: 105px;
    width: 205px;
    background-color: white;
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: 0;
    
}

.highdiv{
    height: 55px;
    width: 205px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: 0;
    

}

.lowdiv{
    height: 50px;
    width: 205p;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: 0;
    
}

.logocontainer{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: 0;
      
    
}
```

```html
<?php
    $i = 1;
    while($i <= 30) {    
                    
        echo'<div class="chartouterdiv">';
        echo'<div class="chartinnerdiv">';                 
        echo'<div class="highdiv">';
        echo'</div>';
        echo'<div class="lowdiv">';
        echo'<div class="logocontainer">';
        echo'</div>'; 
        echo'</div>';
        echo'</div>';
        echo'</div>';
                       
        $i++;                    
    };
```

Comment: Seems like a class could make this so much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `position` for `.chartouterdiv` in CSS:

```css
position: relative;
```

Have a look - https://jsfiddle.net/vyspiansky/34qx1eyg/

Comment: Great Answer! Looks like it works, with anything other than static (absolute, fixed, relative...)

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume . You have a div  of "abc"
Now if you want to change the z index of that perticular div . Use this:

document.getElementById("abc").style.zIndex = "1";

document.getElementById("abc").style.zIndex = "10";

What ever the z-index value you need , just put it.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_zindex.asp

If I understood the question wrong , please comment or reply , so that I can understand it better.
Thanks